# cost of unwrapping a std::reference_wrapper

Tags: c++, performance, wrapper, indirection

Given:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template<class T> // Just for overloading purposes
struct behaviour1 : std::reference_wrapper<T const>
{
    using base_t = std::reference_wrapper<T const>;
    using base_t::base_t;

    // This wrapper will never outlive the temporary
    // if used correctly
    behaviour1(T&& t) : base_t(t) {}
};

template<class T>
behaviour1(T&&) -> behaviour1<std::decay_t<T> >;

struct os_wrapper : std::reference_wrapper<std::ostream>
{
    using std::reference_wrapper<std::ostream>::reference_wrapper;

    template<class T>
    os_wrapper& operator<<(behaviour1<T> const& v)
    {
        *this << v.get(); // #1
        return *this;
    }

    template<class U>
    os_wrapper& operator<<(U&& t)
    { this->get() << t; return *this; }
};

int main() { os_wrapper(std::cout) << behaviour1(3); }
```

In line #1, is the indirection actually performed, given that specific use case (a wrapper that is inmediatly unwrapped, and nor copied neither bound to local references except function parameters), or will the compiler just detect that the object is inmediatly unwrapped and just use the original object instead? Which will be a better design otherwise (for example, whether a partial specialization for scalar types that just save a copy of the object will be more efficient)?

I'm interested specifically in `gcc` (version 7, `-O3 -std=c++17`) although I guess both `clang` and `gcc` performs similar optimization techniques.

Comment: Did you take a look at the compiler output? You can check the code generated by `gcc`. If not, you could use https://godbolt.org/. I don't think that inheriting from `std::reference_wrapper` is a good idea in general.

Comment: Providing a compilable (minimal, complete) example would also be nice. Right now, the code doesn't even compile.

Comment: I agree with Jens. `std::reference_wrapper` doesn't have any virtual members. Just make it a member variable instead of inheriting from it.

Comment: @MillieSmith That's a false myth. I don't mean to use any of those wrappers using pointers to base class or create dynamic memory or something. The use of the class is delimited and well defined and there's nothing wrong with inheriting from it in that case.

Comment: Code updated to a shorter form.

Comment: It's overly risky. If the C++ committee had wanted people to inherit from `std::reference_wrapper`, they would have made it virtual. I see nothing in your question that dictates that you need to inherit from it. And it's so simple to implement you might as well write your own with a virtual destructor if you're going to derive from it.

Comment: @MillieSmith "If the C++ committee had wanted people to use `std::reference_wrapper` **polymorphically**, they would have made it virtual" (I guess you mean the destructor being virtual, because a "virtual object" has no meaning in C++).

Comment: I agree with @Peregring-lk here, inheriting non-polymorphically is nothing to be ashamed of. Stop attacking something that is irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The expected cost of using methods of `std::reference_wrapper` in an optimized build is 0 because all `std::reference_wrapper` code can be inlined. [The assembly output of statement `os_wrapper(std::cout) << behaviour1(3);` is](https://godbolt.org/g/pFSAeF):

```
movl    $3, %esi
movl    std::cout, %edi
call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(int)
```

Inlining is what enables zero-overhead abstractions which Stroustrup likes to mention.