# Are there any downsides to using `std::reference_wrapper<T>` as an always-valid member variable instead of a pointer?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am having a quite common problem. I have a class that must store a non-owning pointer to a different class object.

I know that:

- The lifetime of the reference object is guaranteed to outlive the instance.
- The referenced object is passed in a constructor and does not change with the exception of moves or assignment.
- It is never invalid.
- It is used in many methods.
- It can be shared by many instances.

Think of e.g. a `logger` class which is not global.

These points lead me to this solution using a reference variable which guarantees validity:

```cpp
struct Foo{};

struct Bar{
    Bar(Foo& foo):m_foo(foo){}

Foo& m_foo;
};
```

The big downside is `Bar` is unnecessarily almost immutable - no assignment, no move.

The usual thing I did was to store `Foo` as a pointer instead. This solves most of the issues except that it is no longer very clear that the pointer is always valid. Furthermore it adds a small new issue that it can be invalidated in any method, which should not happen. (Making it const has the same downside as `&`). That makes me add `assert(m_foo)` to every method for peace of mind.

**So, I was thinking about just storing `std::reference_wrapper<Foo>`. It is always valid and it keeps `Bar` mutable. Are there any downsides compared to a simple pointer?**
I know that any method can still
point it to e.g. a local variable but let's say that does not happen because it is perhaps hard to obtain a new valid instance of `Foo`. At least it is harder than simple `=nullptr;`

I know this approach is used for containers like `std::vector` so I assume it is okay, but I would like to know if there is any catch I should look for.

Comment: Possible downsides would be some kind of performance or storage overhead, but it seems there is none: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46957595/cost-of-unwrapping-a-stdreference-wrapper

Comment: @SvenNilsson Thank you, I missed that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Foo` is a struct you need to invoke `get()` every time you access any member or field of Foo. With reference or pointer you could use '.' or '->' respectively for member access. So `reference_wrapper` is not "transparent" in that regard. (There is currently also no way of making it "transparent" in C++, which would be nice of course).

There will be no runtime overhead but code will be congested with `get()` calls.

If that is not of a concern for you then there are no downsides of using `reference_wrapper` instead of a pointer. (In fact `reference_wrapper` is implemented by using a pointer member)

EDIT: also if you only need to call one or two member functions of `Foo` one could inherit from `reference_wrapper` and add a call stub. But that perhaps may be overkill ...

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I did not know about needing `get()`, that's a bummer. I expected it to work like e.g. `std::unique_ptr`. Could you please expand on why is not possible to get such behaviour? Why cannot be `operator->` misued to return `T*`? Is this about non-overloadability of `<dot>`?

Comment: Yes, it's about `.` not being overloadable and `*`/`->` not being appropriate for a non-pointer. And congestion with `get()` is reduced by leveraging implicit contextual conversion to `T&`.

Comment: @underscore_d Thanks, although I believe `->` would be no less valid than `<<` is for streams - you get used to it. Yes, `get()` is unnecessary when passing `Foo` around, but calling its methods needs it and that is what I will be mostly doing :/

Comment: Well, maybe one day the proposal(s) for `operator .` will get somewhere!

Comment: @Quimby  Overloading '->' would work, but then perhaps one could just use a pointer in the first place. Operator '.' is not overloadable, there have been proposals (even by Stroustrup) but were not succeesful. In case you only need to call a member function for 'Foo' you could inherit from `reference_wrapper` and add a stub member. This will not work for data members though.

Comment: Ok, thank everyone for help, I will just stick to a pointer for a while.

Comment: @underscore_d  Yes, that would be nice. C++ needs full support for the proxy pattern!

Comment: @Quimby Understandable, I would use pointer too :-)

Comment: @Quimby I don't see the downside of overloading -> and using it instead of get() - I think it is no less intuitive than if you were using a pointer but it is always pointing to a valid object so for me it is the best of both.  Why do you think a pointer is better?

Comment: Alternatively use a private pointer `Foo* m_foo;` and provide a function `Foo& foo() { return *m_foo; }` (plus a `const` overload, most likely) to both use a pointer and prevent external actors from changing the pointer itself, without needing to mess around with `reference_wrapper`.